# How to serve static files on nestjs?

Tags: javascript, express, nestjs

I have a nestjs project, in the root of the site there is an uploads folder, there are files of different extensions there. How should I process them?

http://localhost:7777/uploads/audio/85/0.mp3
http://localhost:7777/uploads/movie/85/0.mp4

When I do this I get an error:

**{
"statusCode": 404,
"message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'G:\myproject\uploads\index.html'"
}**

In App.module I did everything as in the nest documentation:

```
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';


@Module({
   imports: [
     ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
       rootPath: join(__dirname, '../../../', 'uploads'),
     }),
     UsersModule
```

Main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './App/app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';


async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const port = configService.get('PORT'); 
  app.enableCors();
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe()); 
  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks inside `uploads` folder already, it might be trying to look for `uploads` inside `uploads` if you know what I mean.

So, you can explicitly mention it as a URL prefix like this

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'uploads'),
      // Tell NestJS to serve the files under ~/uploads/
      serveRoot: '/uploads/',
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### Update

I ran the repository you mentioned in comments and added a console log. Looks like it's trying to access `uploads` under the `dist` folder. This might be your other issue.

[image: debug]

#### Update 2

I managed to get it working on the repository you added in the comments, by 2 things:

- Adding a 3rd `..` to account for the `dist` folder
- More importantly: moving the code to run in a factory method

Like this:

```
    ServeStaticModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => {
        const uploadsPath = join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'uploads');
        return [
          {
            rootPath: uploadsPath,
            serveRoot: '/uploads/',
          },
        ];
      },
    }),
```

Result:

[image: Success]

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. UPD link

[link](https://prnt.sc/0LolJpwYhhOx)

Comment: Are you sure you need two `..` in there? If `AppModule.ts` is directly under `src` not in a child filder, and `uploads` and `src` are both directly under `myproject`, then you need only one `..`

Comment: Here's how I wrote it - https://prnt.sc/fHFAE1GIVpv3

Comment: Yeah, looks like it might work with `join(__dirname, '..', 'uploads'),` -- that's a single `'..'` instead of 2.

Comment: It doesn't work with just one colon either. 
```rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'uploads') = error``` 

```rootPath: join(__dirname, '.', 'uploads') = error ```

```rootPath: join(__dirname,  'uploads')  = error 
```
I've already tried everything I can, I can't understand why nothing works.

Comment: I updated my answer with the one `'..'` -- can you please show me the error in this case? Thanks.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/FhFmlUIy2WWY

Comment: Update screen - https://prnt.sc/E4KlQyzxp7Ve

Comment: Oh. Now that I see that `app.module.ts` is not directly under `src` but `src/app` instead, your two `..` are actually correct. I assume you tried restarting the server? Also, do you have a global prefix like `app.setGlobalPrefix('api')`?

Comment: No, I didn’t use the global prefix app.setGlobalPrefix Can you tell me how to register it correctly in my case?

Comment: I read about app.setGlobalPrefix and understood what it is for now, which means there is no need to register it. I didn’t write it down))

Comment: I updated the topic, added the main.ts code

Comment: Are you saying that the answer works after your suggested edit? or were you meaning to edit your own question? Forgive me if it's a dumb question!

Comment: No, it does not work.

I just added some extra code from my project. main.ts to show that I did not use app.setGlobalPrefix )))

Forgive me, I don't speak English well)

Comment: My repo - https://github.com/xonarin/youtube/tree/dev

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did some debugging for you and I think I found the issue. It's looking for uploads folder under dist not under the app itself. At least this is what I get when I start the app with npm run start. See this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXV2z.png

Comment: Yes you are right. It actually looks for data in dist/uploads.

https://prnt.sc/uPzNovDH5JSG

Thanks, now I think I can solve this problem myself.

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: Check my updated answer. I got it working and tested it!

Comment: For the production version it won't hurt you that it's in the `dist` folder, but it's probably a good idea to load it from the `env` file using the config service (I omitted this for simplicity). You can do this easily in the factory, just inject the config service into it.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me)) I wish you all the best, and most importantly health!)